# How to remove the space while printing with newline \n?

Tags: python

Input:

```
a = input("enter-")
b = input("enter-")
c = input("enter-")
print(a, "\n", b, "\n", c, "\n")
```

Output:

```
enter-line1
enter-line2
enter-line3
line1
 line2
 line3
```

How to remove the space before `line2` and `line3`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), `print` function prints the arguments separated by default by a space. One of the several ways to remove spaces is to pass to `print` a single string, like so: `print("\n".join([a, b, c]))`

Comment: Try setting a \n in the print separator.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the argument **sep** of print. By default, the separator is space:

```py
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

```py
>>> print(a, b, c, sep='\n')
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: Great, that worked. My sincere thanks.

Comment: @captainclever please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` function has more arguments than string and looks like this

```
print(object(s), sep=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

Default separator is `' '` so space will be added between every element.
To print without spaces, you need to use it like this

```
print(a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n", sep='')
```

Comment: why the weird `object(s)` in the first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `print` statement with Python and commas in between will naturally give spaces.  For example, if I used `print(a,b,c)`, then the output would be `line1 line2 line3`.  Here, by using `print(a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n")`, you are putting a space after you put a newline.  So either use separate print statements or use the `"\n"` as the separator between the arguments without using commas.